# What is the difference in these 2 javascript expressions?

Tags: javascript

I am refactoring some javascript code and came across this expression:

```
false === options.onSubmit.call(this)
```

What would be the purpose to put the `false` first?  Is there a difference between that expression and this expression?

```
options.onSubmit.call(this) === false
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Answer (score 2):

What I think the best benefit of that is you can't accidentally do `assignment` instead of `compare`. It comes in place basically with `==` check.

When you want to compare two values like bellow

```
someVariable === false
```

OR

```
someVariable == false
```

could be accidently

```
someVariable = false
```

But

```
false = someVariable
```

Will cause a error **ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment**. So you will get rid of that mistake.

Comment: Besides this approach is more readable than the opposite.

Comment: @VisioN yes I agree with you, but every thing has it's own pros & cons.

Comment: They'll both cause the same error given that example.

Comment: @cookiemonster could be just talking about why this way is used.

Comment: Sure. Point is that there's no difference the way this is used in your example. It could be confusing to people since it doesn't show a real world example where it would actually make a difference.